# How to solve segmentation error in C program

Tags: c, printf

Guys I'm getting a segmentation error, exactly this error to be more specific:

```
Segmentation fault
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?  my code is simple I don't know why the error, does anyone know how to solve it step by step?

I'm using this command to convert my c file into an executable `gcc test.c -o test` then I run my `test` file with`./test`, but then I get that error as I said above.

**My code in c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int age;
int aget;
int total;
printf("Input your age: ");
scanf("%i", &idade);
printf("Input your age two: ");
scanf("%i", &age);
base = age + aget;
printf(total);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: base is not declared

Comment: also `printf` stands for print formatted - so you need to supply a format string

Comment: "*then I run my test*" You can't run that because it doesn't compile. Please post real code.

Comment: This will not even compile, so whatever you run is not the same as what you show.

Comment: Friend, I'm posting the code from my file `test.c` I use this code `gcc test.c -o test` to generate me the test executable and then I run it, but my code in c is from the file **test.c** understood  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `base` is undeclared.
Variable `idade` is undeclared.
It should be `printf("%d",base)` if your are using base.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int age;
    int aget;
    int total;
    printf("Input your age: ");
    scanf("%i", &age);
    printf("Input your age two: ");
    scanf("%i", &aget);
    total = age + aget;
    printf("%d",total);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake, but the segmentation failure error continued, after adding `% d` before displaying the total value solved the problem, thanks, I am learning c yet.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` needs a format string. Here we need to tell it `%d` for integer in decimal.

```
total = idade + age;
printf("%d\n", total);
```

Some random resource on how to use printf: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html